# how to build a query when thousands of same documents exists in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build a simple auto-complete where the data is coming from Elasticsearch and I seem to be running into problems.

I keep event attendees registration information in Elasticsearch.

```
registration:{
   name: "John Doe",
   title: "Mr",
   country: "AU",
   position: "Employee"
}
```

As there are hundreds of events, "John Doe" has perhaps hundreds of hits in ES

I am building an auto-complete and I want to display only the unique version of John Doe.

E.g.

- "John Doe", "Australia", "Mr", "Employee"
- "John Doe, "USA", "Mr", "Employee"
- "John Doe", "USA", "Dr.", "Owner"

in the index I might have 50 of line 1, 20 of line 2 and 100 of line 3.

As far as I see I can not use buckets as they aggregate on a single line and I need the whole document.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

like

select name, title, country, position from table group by name, title, country, position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to use buckets.. You can use the concatenated version of the text as the term to aggregate upon.
you can use a script if you want,

e.g.

```
"terms":{
     "script":"doc['name'].value 
             + '|' + doc['title'].value 
             + '|' + doc['country'].value 
             + '|' + doc['position'].value"
}
```

for each created bucket you will get a key with the values of the fields that you have included in your script.

However, you may like to check [Completion Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) in elasticsearch, you wont have to handle duplicates explicitly.